# Swift 1.2 Parse Save in Background Errors

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I recently made the switch to Swift 1.2 and noticed it broke a small amount of my Parse functionality. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why the version update broke these originally working methods and how I should solve them. The two errors I am seeing are within the same `.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` function.

The first error is on my `.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` line:

`Function signature '(Bool, NSError!) -> Void' is not compatible with expected type '@objc_block (Bool, NSError!) -> Void'`

The second is located within an else statement that happens if there is a signup error, `NSString { error = errorString }`

`'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?`

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController {


    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
            action in



        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func registerUser(sender: AnyObject) {

        var error = ""

        if usernameTextField.text == nil || emailTextField.text == nil || passwordTextField.text == nil {

            error = "Please enter a username, email and password"

        }


        if error != "" {

            displayAlert("Error In Form", error: error)

        } else {

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()

            user.username = usernameTextField.text
            user.password = passwordTextField.text
            user.email = emailTextField.text

            user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in
                if signupError == nil {

                    println(user.username)
                    println(user.password)
                    println(user.email)


                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulRegistration", sender: self)

                    /*self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)*/

                } else {

                    if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
                        error = errorString
                    } else {

                        error = "Please try again later."

                    }


                    self.displayAlert("Could Not Sign Up", error: error)

                }
            }


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, the NSError needs to be an optional, not implicitly unwrapped

eg:

```
.saveInBackgroundWithBlock( { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first one makes sense. One thing two note for the second issue is that this is a conditional statement so instead of `as!`, an optional `as?` should be used for conditional downcasting.

Comment: Great. Wish I could edit my use of "to" in my comment :) Thanks again